# where is Jenkins default maven-repository?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, devops

I have `Jenkins ver.2.121.1` installed on `Windows Server 2012 R2` along with `Apache Maven 3.5.2`.
In `localhost:8080/systeminfo` link, `$MAVEN_HOME` environment variable is set correctly (to `C:\\apache-maven-3.5.2\`) and maven saves my custom libraries in `~\.m2\.repository\` but Jenkins saves the custom libraries(like ojdbc, ...) in 
 another directory (in `C:\\Program Files(x86)\Jenkins\maven-repositories\0\`).

In jenkins `config.xml` (in `C:\\Program Files(x86)\Jenkins\config.xml`), no line is specified about maven local repositories (for example nothing is defined like `<localRepository>${env.HOME}/.m2/repository</localRepository>`).
Is there any clear reason why Jenkins uses its own maven repository directory? Should I addres my own maven directory to force jenkins give priority to it?

Comment: Does your jenkins user have a `settings.xml` file? perhaps in `.m2` ?

Comment: No, it just have a `config.xml` in `$JENKINS_HOME\config.xml`. Also there is a file named `settings.xml` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\tools\hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation\C_Program_Files_apache-maven-3.5.2_bin_mvn\conf\settings.xml` but it contains default maven instructions which are all commented.

Comment: What about if you go into Configure Jenkins -> Managed Files, is there a settings.xml type of file there?

Comment: No, there is no files defined in `http://localhost:8080/configfiles/`.

Comment: JENKINS_HOME_DIR/.m2/repository ?

Comment: @aurelius no this path does not exist. As an alternative to all of these answers my jenkins uses $JENKINS_HOME/maven-repositories!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `http://localhost:8080/configure` and you can see and specify "Local Maven Repository" there.

[image: Maven Project Configuration]

Comment: My Local Maven Repository is set to default; But as I have stated above it is not applied to jenkins and jenkins uses its own rules.

Answer (score 1):

If using a Jenkinsfile configuration you may add Jenkins default repository to get artifacts when installing/compiling with maven. Like this:

```
script {
      try {
        sh 'mvn -Dmaven.repo.local=/data/jenkins/repository/ clean install'
      } catch (errorDescription) {
       // do whatever you need to notify error
      }
```